# Function fscanf ignoring space separator in .txt file

Tags: c, struct, malloc, memcpy, scanf

I am trying to scan a text file of the following format in `C`:

```
key01 value01
key02 value02
key03 value03
```

I want to take the key and value strings and assign them to a struct I have created:

```
struct Mapping
{
  char  key[sizeof(char) * 5];
  char  value[sizeof(char) * 7];
} MapElement;
```

My code to do this is the following:

```
void initialize_server_map(struct Mapping serverMap[])
{
  char* fileName = "server1.txt";
  FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
  char *lineKey = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
  char *lineValue = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
  int i = 0;
  while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s", lineKey, lineValue) != EOF) {
    struct Mapping mapping;
    memcpy(mapping.key, lineKey, sizeof(char) * 5);
    memcpy(mapping.value, lineValue, sizeof(char) * 7);
    printf("key: %s value: %s\n", mapping.key, mapping.value);
    serverMap[i] = mapping;
    i++;
  }
  fclose(fp);
}

int main(void)
{
  int size = 4;
  struct Mapping serverMap[size];
  initialize_server_map(serverMap);
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
key: key01value01 value: value01
key: key02value02 value: value02
key: key03value03 value: value03
key: key04value04 value: value04
```

Naturally, I would like this output instead:

```
key: key01 value: value01
key: key02 value: value02
key: key03 value: value03
key: key04 value: value04
```

I'm sure it has to do something with the way I am allocating my memory. Can someone please help me solve this? Also, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Also, I know for a fact that they keys and values will always be of lengths 5 and 7

Comment: In C, strings are terminated with NUL bytes, which occupy one byte. You should (almost) never use `memcpy` to copy strings; use `strcpy` which will correct NUL-terminate the copy. Remember to leave room for the NUL byte in your arrays and in your mallocs. And `char[sizeof(char) * 5]` is just plain wrong. The number in the declaration is the number of units, not the number of bytes (so `int v[5]` has enough space for 5 ints, no matter how big an int might be). Fortunately, sizeof(char) is always one.

Comment: You are forgetting to add `+1` for the `null-terminating` character necessary if you are going to treat them as strings.

Comment: 4 Answers/comments - all consistent -- I'd say that's a wrap..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing undefined behavior due to out of bound access of arrays.

In order to store `"key01"`, you need an array of size at least `6` -- `5` for the characters and one for the terminating null character.

Similarly, you need an array of size at least `8` for storing `"value01"`.

You are declaring the arrays with sizes `5` and `7`, respectively. As a consequence, you are modifying the array out of bounds when used in

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s", lineKey, lineValue) != EOF) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, at least you've forgotten about the space for trailing '\0' in strings. So if you have 5-char string, you should allocate 6 chars.

But generally the whole approach is quite fragile. What if keys in your input data would have more than 5 characters length? The traditional approach is to use "big enough" buffers for `scanf` (say few hundred bytes), limit possible string length in `scanf` using length limiters in the format (e.g. "%20s" instead of "%s") and then allocate rquired space via `strdup`.

So the whole chunk would look like:

```
struct Mapping {
   char* key;
   char* value;
};
...
char lineKey[51];
char lineValue[51];
while (fscanf(fp, "%50s %50s", lineKey, lineValue) != EOF) {
    struct Mapping* mp = (struct Mapping*)malloc(sizeof(struct Mapping));
    assert(mp);
    mp->key = strdup(lineKey);
    mp->value = strdup(lineValue);
    ...   
}
```